# Flex:How to get all rows in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
private function editCellEnd(event:AdvancedDataGridEvent):void
```

In this method I can get `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` in event. I also can get `DataGird` from `event.target as AdvancedDataGrid` . 'columns' can return all  columns.

But why doesn't `AdvancedDataGrid` have a property that can return all rows in it.

How do I get all rows in `AdvancedDataGrid`?

Comment: have you tried `myGrid.dataProvider` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if rowIndex is 3,this row data's  index in dataProvider is 3.        Maybe I have 4 items in dataProvider ,but  myGrid only display 3 rows. because i set 1 of items invisible.       So i only need 3 displayed rows,but if  using dataProvider, i will get 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line

```
var visibleData:Object = myGrid.mx_internal::getListVisibleData();
```

visibleData is a map of UID to the renderers that are visible.
Hope this helps